# Mongodb .aggregrate meets the $match, but excludes embedded docs that don't $match?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to aggregate only the documents where 'sessionUsername' is in the 'to' array where he/she has also set his/her view of the message to view.inbox:true & view.archive:false & view.bin:false..

(docs that meet these parameters are further filtered by the $or messagingQuery)

**Why are the resulting docs excluding the values of any additional users that exist in the 'to' array?**

*I have a schema structure of embedded docs that looks like this:*

```
var MessageSchema = new Schema({
    from      : [UserMessageSchema],
    to        : [UserMessageSchema],
    message   : String,
    updated   : Date
});

var UserMessageSchema = new Schema({
  user        : { "type": Schema.ObjectId, "ref": "User" },
  username    : String,
  view : {
    inbox       : Boolean,
    outbox      : Boolean,
    archive     : Boolean,
    bin         : Boolean
  }
    updated   : Date
});
```

*And an aggregate query that looks like this:*

```
Models.Messages.aggregate([

    // Match documents
    { "$match": {
        "to": { 
            "$elemMatch": {
               "username": sessionUsername,
               "view.inbox": true,
               "view.archive": false,
               "view.bin": false
            }
        },
        "$or": messagingQuery
    }},

    // Unwind to de-normalize
    { "$unwind": "$to" },

    // Match the array elements      
    { "$match": {
       "to.username": sessionUsername,
       "to.view.inbox": true,
       "to.view.archive": false,
       "to.view.bin": false
    }},

    // Group back to the original document
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "from": { "$first": "$from" },
       "to": { "$push": "$to" },
       "message": { "$first": "$message" },
       "updated": { "$first": "$updated" }
    }},

    // Sort by updated, most recent first (descending)
    {"$sort": {"updated": -1}}

], function (err, docs) {
```

Comment: Because you are asking it to. That is what the second `$match` just after the `$unwind` is doing. If you don't want this then just use `.find()`

Comment: @NeilLunn that makes perfect sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NeilLunn for pointing to the answer: a second $match, after the $unwind, excludes fields that don't $match the second $match.

*Here's a find():*

```
Models.Messages.find(
   { 
        "to": { 
            "$elemMatch": {
               "username": sessionUsername,
               "view.inbox": true,
               "view.archive": false,
               "view.bin": false
            }
        },
        "$or": messagingQuery
   }
).sort([['updated','descending']]).exec(function (err, docs) {
```